# Why does this logo not display in Firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

Compare the top bar for [Sudomemo Theatre](http://www.sudomemo.net) in both Chrome and Firefox. I've been hunting around for the reason why the "Sudomemo Theatre" logo won't display in Firefox; I've tried both Linux, Windows, and Mac. I can only conclude that it comes down to the rendering engine.

But *why* won't it display, and how can I fix it? I'd like to understand the issue at its core. It appears to me that Firefox is not properly properly rendering the css content attribute.

Thanks!

Take notice of the top floating menu bar; it should have a 'Sudomemo Theatre' logo on the left. It displays properly in Chrome for Windows, and Linux (Chromium), but not Firefox. I can't assume that everyone has the latest version.

[image: Firefox][image]

Comment: It displays for me in Firefox 32.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Z5NxIiC.png http://i.imgur.com/nEqz72G.png

Comment: It appears to me that Firefox is not properly properly rendering the css content attribute?

Comment: (Edit to above: I was looking at the logo in the big checkerboard, not in the top navbar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Firefox only supports the `content` CSS attribute with the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-class, but not with a "bare" element.

Changing the rule to this works, although the image is now too large:

```
a.navbar-brand:before {
    content: url("/images/sudomemotheatrelogomedium.png");
    padding: 10px;
}
```

For more info, see the [documentation of content on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content). This seems to be [how the standard is written](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html), so technically Chrome might be wrong here by working as-is.